# How to change the tooltip in rails for has_and_belongs_to_many option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-admin

I wanted to change the text on the tool tip displayed in UI for Add new User created through rails_admin and device gems.

I have created a sample application called post which shows basic CRUD operations in rails. To this, I have created a admin panel using rails_admin.

I have two models Post.rb and User.rb

Post.rb:

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user
end

User.rb:

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

# Include default devise modules. Others available are:

# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

has_many :post

end

When I declare this "belongs_to" and "has_many" association between  User and Post model a multiselect is created automatically in "add new"  tab of User in admin panel. And when i hover the content of Multiselect it gives default tooltip the content itself. I have used rails_admin gem to create admin panel.
Now my problem is I want to change this default tooltip content. I want to dynamically show tooltip from post table on multiselect when we hover its content . How can I do that ?? or can I do that??

Comment: Please include your view code to aid other developers when answering your question.

Comment: I have not added any view, rails_admin automatically created the views for CURD operations for Users. has_many option in the model provided the Multiple Select option for Post in the Create New User View.

Comment: Rails_admin has extensive documentation, that really should be your first point of call https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki it's likely that you will need to extend the functionality provided by rails admin. Your question is about a specific gem, you'll get much more interest if you can provide a full example, illustrating what you want to do.

Comment: Updated my question with detailed description.